# Python asyncio: how single thread can handle mutiple things simultaneously?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Hi I am new to asyncio and concept of event loops (Non-blocking IO)

```
async def subWorker():
    ...

async def firstWorker():
    await subWorker()


async def secondWorker():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.ensure_future(firstWorker())
asyncio.ensure_future(secondWorker())
loop.run_forever()
```

here, when code starts, `firstWorker()` is executed and paused until it encounters `await subWorker()`. While `firstWorker()` is waiting, `secondWorker()` gets started.

Question is, when `firstWorker()` encounters `await subWorker()` and gets paused, the computer then will execute `subWorker()` and `secondWorker()` at the same time. Since the program has only 1 thread now, and I guess the single thread does `secondWorker()` work. Then who executes `subWorker()`? If single thread can only do 1 thing at a time, who else does the other jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption that `subWorker` and `secondWorker` execute at the same time is false.

The fact that `secondWorker` simply sleeps means that the available time will be spent in `subWorker`.

`asyncio` by definition is single-threaded; see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html):

> This module provides infrastructure for writing single-threaded concurrent code

The event loop executes a task at a time, switching for example when one task is blocked while waiting for I/O, or, as here, voluntarily sleeping.

Comment: I gave a wrong example then. Then what if secondWorker() does cpu bound job, not `await asyncio.sleep(1)`? Then subWorker and secondWorker execute at the same time?

Comment: No, then one executes before the other. Updated the answer slightly.

Comment: hmm.. then, why asyncio is called "async programming module"? is there way that  two being run at the same time concurrently?

Comment: Again, the asyncio architecture runs a single event loop which interrupts individual tasks when they are in I/O wait. When you try to print something, you are in I/O wait while the output buffer gets handled by the operating system. In which order exactly buffers get handled over on the OS side is obviously OS-dependent and basically unpredictable as far as Python is concerned.  This is "concurrent" in the sense that the interrupted task is "in progress" somewhere else outside of your program (perhaps with a DMA transfer running without the CPU doing anything, etc).

Comment: That being said, some tasks which can be handled by OS (or something that is not CPU) can be run concurrently, while cpu-bound jobs be run at same time? And 2 or more cpu-bound jobs cannot be run at the same time? Then I guess asyncio is asynchronous only for non-cpu-bound jobs. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the `io` in the name means this particular component handles I/O concurrency. The basic `async` still lets you handle some async tasks in what on some level can be regarded as concurrent execution, though (of course, just like threads) this is an abstraction which in the end runs on a single CPU.

Comment: Okay. I understood. I wonder what is the range of jobs that can be run concurrently or considered as I/O. I am using python telegram-bot wrapper [link](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) in my code, and I send message per a bot using `async await()`, but nothing else seems to run while sending message. Thanks for your great answer:)

Comment: I/O is pretty simple, it's anything which touches the `open()`, `read()`, `write()`, and `close()` system calls.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answers:) Then, python considers whether I/O or not automatically? And I guess networking (via socket or whatever) is considered as a kind of filesystem, and related to open(), read(), and close()

Comment: The quote was not in the documentation since 3.7. Does this answer still hold for the newer versions of Python?

Comment: @z11i I'm not sure which aspect exactly you mean. If you mean does the `async` architecture fundamentally remain "one task at a time, no threads or parallel processes (unless you put them there yourself)" then the answer is yes. Probably read an intro to `async` for a fuller picture. I guess they took out "single-treaded" because nothing _forces_ you to abstain from using threads, though you will probably get yourself into a mess if you do that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little old now, but I've found the visualization from the `gevent` docs (about 1 screen down, beneath "Synchronous & Asynchronous Execution") to be helpful while teaching asynchronous flow control to coworkers: http://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/

The most important point here is that only one coroutine is *running* at any one time, even though many may be *in process*.